# Sample Grails 2.14 app not working in Tomcat

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

```
Grails 2.1.4
Tomcat 7.0.37
Java 1.7
Window 7
```

I created Sample Grails app in eclipse, i run with run-app. it is working fine and able to open in brower also.

But for same application, i build .war file with grails:maven-install. And i am trying to deploy, But i am getting below error:

Mar 26, 2013 11:56:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/HelloGrails-0.1] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 26, 2013 11:56:26 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/HelloGrails-0.1] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.MyThreadLocal] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$MyThreadLocal@644aa32b]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@601e8f7d]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Mar 26, 2013 11:56:26 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/HelloGrails-0.1] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.ThreadLocalMapHandler] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo$ThreadLocalMapHandler@639ca35]) and a value of type [java.lang.ref.SoftReference] (value [java.lang.ref.SoftReference@3c0a60c4]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.

Please help me..............

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: "startup failed due to previous errors", what's the rest of the log?

Answer (score 0):

create a file named logging.properties in WEB-INF/classes with following content:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

Restart apache and look to the stacktrace